# rails deploy migrating run with root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When i do deploy, migrating run as root. 
i have error:
Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
But in my /shared/config/database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: sa

development:
  <<: *default
  user: root
  password: ""

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  user: sa
  password: "mypassss"
```

my capfile:

```
 require "capistrano/rvm"
 require "capistrano/bundler"
 require "capistrano/rails/migrations"
 require "capistrano/passenger"
```

Why migrating run as root but not as user sa?

Comment: Have you created a user SA on the production mysql db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yhe problem is that i use user: sa , but need to use username: sa.
Solved